# Right border of a div does not get shown sometimes

Tags: html, css, angular, border

So, I have a list of divs which look like this:

[image]

As you can see, those cards have a gray border. But the cards on the right side somehow dont have that border. This is the code I use in my image component:

```
.image-container {
  border: 1px solid var(--IDNFNGS-dropdown-selected) !important;
}
```

The parent component renders the list of images. Here is some relevant code from that list component:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

//the whole div element
.image { 
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
}
```

I am wondering why the right border doesnt show up when the image-div is on the right side? Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add box-sizing.

```
.image-container {
  border: 1px solid var(--IDNFNGS-dropdown-selected) !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```